# Я хочу увеличить arraylength в несколько раз. Как это сделать?

Tags: java

Я хочу увеличить arraylength в несколько раз. Как это сделать? мне нужно написать с использованием if().

Вот код:

```
public class VectorZ
{
    private final int INTIAL_SIZE = 10;
    private int [] array;
    private int currentIndex;

    public VectorZ(){
    {
        array = new intpINITIAL_SIZE];
        currentIndex = 0;
    }
    public void add(int element)
    {
        array[currentIndex] = element;
    }
    public void remove(int at)
    {
        for (int i = at; i<array.lenght-1;i++)
        {
            array[i] = array[i+1];
        }
        array[array.lenght-1] = 0;
    }
    public void print()
    {
        for(int element: array){
            System.out.print(element + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 1):

пересоздать массив с большей размерностью

```
int[] a = new int[10];

if(a.length==10)
    a = new int[a.length *5 ];

System.out.println(a.length);
```

если массив не пустой, то можно в новый перенести старые данные

```
int newlength = a.length*2;
int[] newArray = new int[newlength];
System.arrayCopy(a, 0, newArray, 0, a.length);
```